# What exactly is "task type" in gradle?

Tags: gradle

I can declare a type for a gradle task and doing so seems to inherit some methods. For example:

```groovy
task myCopyTask(type: Copy){
  from "foo"
  into "bar"
}
```

So, I think `myCopyTask` is an instance of `org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy` class, yes? And if I declare a task without any type, it is an instance of `org.gradle.api.DefaultTask`? Sorry for the basic question. I have been reading the gradle guide like [this page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:configuring_tasks) but it isn't clear to me what `type:` exactly is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just add a `println` and find out yourself?

```groovy
task myCopyTask(type: Copy) {
    ... 
}
println "Type is $myCopyTask.class.name"
```

Comment: That's true. Sorry, I didn't think of using println like that. Thanks. And the actual classes are what I thought (or close to) org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy_Decorated
org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated

Comment: But what it is needed for?

Answer (score 6):

To get the type of an existing task, you can make use of Gradle's built-in `help` task using the `--task` command line option. The `--task` option takes in a task path for any task in the project. Here is an example using the `help` task on itself:

```
# ./gradlew help --task help                               

> Task :help                                        
Detailed task information for help                  

Path                                                
     :help                                          

Type                                                
     Help (org.gradle.configuration.Help)           

Options                                             
     --task     The task to show help for.          

Description                                         
     Displays a help message.                       

Group                                               
     help
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, I was scanning the docs all day and did not find anything.

Answer (score 5):

It's already answered but this might help to understand as well.

They're the subclasses of the type [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html). Once you define a type for your task, you get to access/set/configure that particular task's properties. In your case, this is a subclass called "Copy" (as you've already kinda figure out).

Note: Tasks are shipped with various plugins or written by you.

Comment: There's a list of the default available types here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html#N104C2